How to create a context inside a class
I have a class that has a method, I call that method from other class, however I want to do a transform to the string before return.  That transform required context.
Class Car {

 String getColor() {

   AppLocalizations localizations = AppLocalizations.of('context');
   
   return localizations.carColor;

 }

}

As you see, there's no context available in the class.  How can I create a context so my localisation  work within this method?
At the moment, it's hightlight red the context as error The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'

Pass BuildContext to the Class Constructor. BuildContext context;  Car(this.context); And use in another class as  Car car = Car(context);
String color = car.getColor();

Ah I see, now I understand the context is not created inside the class but I have to pass it in.  thanks mate.

To give your function access to BuildContext I would add it as a parameter to your function:
 String getColor(BuildContext context) {

   AppLocalizations localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context);
   
   return localizations.carColor;

 }

I would avoid passing it as an argument of the constructor, due to the temporary nature of contexts. Personally I would pass it as a function argument rather than class constructor argument, so that I wouldn't need to worry about the context being mounted.
